# Accessing class variable defined in parent class in python

Tags: python, oop

I want to set a class variable in a parent class and then manipulate it in a child class. I have code like this:

```
class Parent():
    def unique_to_parent(self):
        self.c = "D"

class Child(Parent):
    def blah(self):
        print(self.c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thing = Child()
    thing.blah()
```

But this results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 16, in <module>
    thing.blah()
  File "./test.py", line 12, in blah
    print(self.c)
AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'c'
```

On the other hand, if modify Child.blah() to be like this:

```
def blah(self):
    super(Child, self).unique_to_parent()
    print(self.c)
```

I get the desired output, "D". This seems wrong to me. What is the point of inheriting if I explicitly need to ask for the data in the method `unique_to_parent` that happens to be unique to the parent? How do I accomplish this simple task in Python 3.6 ?

EDIT:
For reasons, I don't want to instantiate the variable `c` in the `__init__` function of `Child`, although that seems to solve the issue (with possible side effects).

Comment: (1) "c" is an instance variable here (or instance attribute), not a class variable (an attribute of the class). (2) Usual way is to create and set such variable in the constructor of "Parent" and then in the "Child" constructor call the "Parent" constructor to let it do what it has to do.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I tried that, but in `thing.blah` (the child instance) the value of `c` was as it was in Parent's `__init__` function, not `unique_to_parent`, even though a method in parent had changed the value of `c` in the meantime. (Need to verify that)

Comment: your first example doesn't call `unique_to_parent` so `c` is never even instantiated. one thing you can do is `class Parent: c = "D"` (where `c = "D"` is in a new line), and you should be able to automatically get `child.blah()`. or if you wanted to keep the way you're initializing variables, you could also just do `thing = Child()` then `thing.unique_to_parent()` then `thing.blah()`

Comment: So, *class variables* are mutable *and* must be instantiated in the __init__ function?

Comment: @kbunarjo the last strategy you mention may work out for me.

Comment: @Lucky If the instance attribute was changed it is changed for all methods accessing it because all methods access the very same attribute.

Comment: Class and instance variables are mutable and it is common practice to initiate instance variables in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

To access an attribute of a parent class, the attribute has to be created first. To do this the function in which the variable is declared (In your case `unique_to_parent`) has to be called. To do this there are two ways:

- One, is to initialize the parent in the constructor of the child class and then call the function in which the variable is declared (In your case `unique_to_parent`). This can also be used to access the variables declared in the constructor of the parent class itself. Your code with this:

### Code (1st way)

```py
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.unique_to_parent()

    def unique_to_parent(self):
        self.c = "D"

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def blah(self):
        print(self.c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thing = Child()
    thing.blah()
```

- Another, is to call directly the function in which the variable is declared from the child class using `super()` like in @kbunarjo's answer. This method is not recommended as it disrupts the flow of the program and I don't think there is a great reason for not initializing the parent class like in the first way.

I hope this helped!